# for loop not working properly with 3 by 3 2D array

Tags: arrays, swing

I have created a 3 by 3 array of buttons but I am finding it hard to loop through each of the button, it won’t loop correctly and I don’t know where I have gone wrong. Below is what I have:

```
JButton[][] button = new JButton[3][3];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                button[i][j] = new JButton();
                panel.add(button[i][j]);

            }
        }
```

Also, I would like them to be put in a 3 by 3 grid, instead of in a line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like @NESPowerGlove said, you are creating a 3x3 grid not a 9x9. 3 by 3 array means 9 buttons and 9 by 9 means 81 buttons.

Comment: you want it 3x3 = 9 buttons; but your code says: 9x9 = 81 buttons... maybe that's what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put them in a 3 by 3 grid, you will need to add GridLayout to your panel, like so;

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
```

and also, you have made a mistake with the way you have used the for loop, instead of having

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
```

you need

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

Because you have used 2D array and created a 3 by 3 array, you need to put 3 in the for loop instead of 9.

So your final code will be something like

```
JButton[][] button = new JButton[3][3];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(340,340);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

          for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            button[i][j] = new JButton();
            panel.add(button[i][j]);

            }
        }
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through as if you made a 9x9 2D array, but you made a 3x3.